# Как установить ToolBar в Matirial Theme?

Tags: java, android, android-style

У меня была установлена тема приложения

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

и в активити я использовал кастомный `toolbar`

```
public final class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainsecond);    

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   }
}
```

Я поменял тему приложения на

```
parent="android:Theme.Material"
```

и в `MainActivity` поменял `extends Activity` (так как с расширением `AppCompatActivity` я так понял, что `Material` не совместим)

и теперь при запуске получаю такие ошибки

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.fittingroom.newtimezone, PID: 18198
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.fittingroom.newtimezone/com.fittingroom.newtimezone.acti vities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line  #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout


Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2:  Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
```

ошибка указывает на строку

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainsecond);
```

В гугле нашел несколько советов, поменять `AppCompatActivity` на `Activity` или тему `parent="android:Theme.Material` на `parent="android:Theme.Material.Light` но ничего не меняется...

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно вашей же ошибке

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.

Если вы пользуете design библиотеку, то надо использовать тему из библиотеки поддержки и активити из неё же.

А тема будет у вас так вполне Material. Почему она не должна быть такой при использовании библиотеки поддержки?..

Comment: Будет матириал? Просто я читаю документацию и там написано, что нужно указать в теме `Theme.Material` ... я так и сделал... или если есть библиотека дизайн то она включает в себя все штучки матириал?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, да, будет. Библиотеки поддержки, включая design, как раз и призваны обеспечить единый дизайн на всех версиях ОС. В данном случае - Material. Когда и если гугл придумает новый дизайн, библиотеки поддержки станут его отображать на всех версиях ОС.